# "invoke-rc.d: initscript freeradius, action "force-reload" failed." while configure freeradious-mysql

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am installing freeradius-mysql.

It Just give me an error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
   freeradius-mysql
```

I tried so many articles but they couldn't help me. Reinstalled it many time but no luck.

whole output

```
sudo apt-get install freeradius-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
freeradius-mysql is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up freeradius-mysql (2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8) ...
reload: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript freeradius, action "force-reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package freeradius-mysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 freeradius-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After sudo apt-get --reinstall install freeradius-mysql

Output :

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install freeradius-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for freeradius-mysql:amd64
```

Comment: What's the whole error output?

Comment: added whole error output

Comment: retry with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install freeradius-mysql`

Comment: Still got some error

Comment: the same? try to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (this migth take a few minutes or hours)

Comment: I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` & `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but had no luck

Comment: Try to reinstall manually `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get purge freeradius-mysql ; sudo apt-get install freeradius-mysql`

Comment: Did that got the same error.

Comment: Do I need to stop mysql services before installing that ??

Comment: hmm, usually it shouldn't make a difference. get the package from[here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freeradius-mysql) and install it using dpkg.

Comment: Oh! Your'e right at first stop freeradius using `freeradius stop`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i did the following:
editing the /var/lib/dpkg/info/freeradius-mysql.postinst file with gedit

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/freeradius-mysql.postinst
```

on almost last of the script you'll find the following:

```
        if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
     invoke-rc.d freeradius force-reload
    else
      /etc/init.d/freeradius force-reload
    fi
;;
```

remove the command 'force-reload' with 'restart', as following:

```
        if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
     invoke-rc.d freeradius restart
    else
      /etc/init.d/freeradius restart
    fi
;;
```

then do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and finish

Answer (score -2):

Just get the package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freeradius-mysql) and install it using

```
dpkg -i freeradius-mysql.deb
```

then restart your server.

Answer (score -2):

There is some bugs in default config and init.d service of freeradius3

1. You must change the field `name=radiusd` in the `/etc/freeradius/radius.conf` to `name=freeradius`
2. Then restart the service
3. If service couldn't be start , you must see the log , maybe the problem is from `allow_vulnerable_openssl = no` and change it to `yes` , 
   run `service freeradius restart`
4. If it's ok, run  `dpkg --configure -a`